# Database where User has Items that are assigned to Calendar

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Im creating a storefront app where there are...

- many Users
- each User has an Inventory
- each Inventory is assigned to a Calendar
- where each Item is a row of the Inventory table
- and each Item is limited to sell only on the day of the week it was assigned by User

So far I've worked out the below way to handle this

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :calendar
end

class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :inventories
end

class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

Being new to Rails, I'm struggling with how to make it so a User can successfully assign their Item to a Calendar day. How can I approach this in my controller/model? Even a small nudge in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure I understand the question correctly, however

you say

where each Item is a row of the Inventory table

in rails you should have

where each Item is a row of the Items table

so

```
class Inventory < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

becomes

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :calendar
end
```

and

```
class Calendar < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :items
end
```

and a user creates an item like this

```
user.calendar.items.create()
```

to get the users 'inventory'

```
@inventory = user.calendar.items.all
```

however I don't really understand your calendar model, I would have thought your user needs many calendars so it can have items for sale on different days. Then you could do something like

```
user.calendar.where(day: 'Tuesday').items.create()
```

Comment: After taking a second look at things your suggestion for many calendars was a good one and I'm revising my table to include Items. Thanks!